What is going on with C/2023 A3 Tsuchinshan-ATLAS!
Recent articles seem to suggest it may be disintegrating but I am confused as to the confidence of this prediction and as to how bright the comet will be at its peak before dimming and disintegrating.
https://people.ast.cam.ac.uk/~jds/coms23.htm#23A3 seems to suggest it is recovering.

https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/?sstr=C%2F2023%20A3&view=OPC https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=90004768

Looks like it made it https://www.space.com/comet-tsuchinshan-atlas
